# Passing around Core Data Stack

Tags: ios, core-data

I am still struggling a lot with the best way to pass around objects within the core data stack.  How I started for reference:

1. App was super simple and single threaded core data access was perfect, only a few views and each needed a MOC.  Started with example code that created the Core Data Stack and one MOC.  MOC was stored in App Delegate.
2. App started to get more complex and finally realized why storing the MOC in the App Delegate was a bad idea.  Refactored code to create the MOC inside the App Delegate and inject the MOC into the root view controller.  From there App Delegate did not hold onto the MOC and view controllers injected it into other controllers that might need it.
3. Started to refactor app views in storyboard.  New tab bar, some nav controllers, split view controller, you know just some different ideas.  Step #2 turned into a nightmare.  Every time I made a change to the app view hierarchy in the storyboard I had to revamp each and every view controller to pass the MOC through the new hierarchy.  Sure apple says this is the right way, but I am not sure I am buying it, very tough to make simple view hierarchy changes without killing code.  Also now I have 4 views at the start of my app that don't even need the MOC.  However those views are the only link from the app delegate to the view controllers that do need the MOC.  So I am stuck injecting the MOC into all those view controllers just so they can pass it along to another view controller without every using the MOC.
4. App is even more complex and now I want a threaded Core Data Stack.  This means passing around the persistent store such that some 'processing' objects can create their own MOC on a background thread.  Should I create some sort of CoreDataStack object that can help manager this?  I.E. object that I can ask for the main thread MOC, or ask for a new 'worker' background MOC.  Seems like now step #3 was even more pointless, every and I mean every view in my app will need access to the main thread MOC and nothing else.  I guess I don't see this one changing for a while, but who knows I have changed a lot since I started ;)

I think the idea of a 'CoreDataStack' object that can manage the distribution of MOCs might be a good idea.  That way at least that object can abstract away the implementation details of the way I choose to implement a threaded stack.  I.E. provide methods to shell out main MOC and background MOC.

That seems great until I start to think about how to pass this stack object around.  I can do exactly what apple recommends and pass this around from controller to controller injecting the main thread MOC into each view controller.  But as I said above about 5 minutes of re-work in a storyboard makes that fall apart extremely quickly.  Not to mention pass MOC to views that don't really need it just so they can pass to the next view in the hierarchy that may need it.

Finally my question.  Is there a better solution for my use case rather than passing around / injecting the MOC into each view controller???

Comment: Working with Core Data and objects in a multi threaded environment can get pretty complex. Have a look at Magical Record, it takes a lot of the pain out of it. https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: 2 is the preferred way, especially when using nested contexts. You can make your implementation slightly easier by using an informal protocol. Concurrency should not introduce problems if you follow the rules and create new contexts for distinct bodies of work. http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/97430076027/a-real-guide-to-core-data-concurrency

Answer (score 1):

You stated

> App started to get more complex and finally realized why storing the MOC in the App Delegate was a bad idea.

What exactly did you not like about this? For the problems you mention the app delegate or a singleton are quite appropriate solutions. I would just remove the app delegate code from all controllers that

- don't need core data
- have an object as an ivar (you can get the managed object context from the managed object subclass)

Unless you have lots of records and need a fetched results controller you can just use the object graph without fetch requests, so the Core Data layer is nicely "abstracted away".

Answer (score -2):

A new technique I use, is proxy objects.  Basically what I do is make a `struct` that mimics the Managed Object.  For all of the read operations I use this mimic object.  If the user is editing the data but hasn't "Saved" it yet, I also use the mimic object.  Only when the user commits to saving the object do I use Core Data.  At that point I call upon my MOC singleton which is created here,

```
// My `AppDelegate` conforms to `UIApplicationDelegateWithPSC`
protocol UIApplicationDelegateWithPSC {

    func providePersistentStoreCoordinator() -> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

}

class ContextManager {

    static let sharedInstance = ContextManager(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

    private init(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType ) { }

    lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
       return {
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Foo", withExtension: "momd")
        let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL!)
        let appDelegateWithPSC = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! UIApplicationDelegateWithPSC
        let psc = appDelegateWithPSC.providePersistentStoreCoordinator()
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let storeURL = (urls[urls.endIndex-1]).appendingPathComponent("Bar")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var store: NSPersistentStore?
        do {
            store = try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            store = nil
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
        let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

        return managedObjectContext
       }()
     }()

}
```

And I call the context as follows:

```
     ContextManager.sharedInstance.context.performAndWait({
        do {
            let foo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Foo", into:  ContextManager.sharedInstance.context) as? Foo
            // `mimicStruct` is the struct i've been using to avoid the headaches of complying with rules for manipulating ManagedObjects.
            foo?.name = mimicStruct.name
            try ContextManager.sharedInstance.context.save()

        } catch {

        }
    })
```

By using the singleton object for my context, i avoid the complexity of multi-threaded code.  Note that I also make this a `performAndWait` which means I am blocking, but since I only do this when I read/write to the database, the user is usually expecting a little pause while a spinner indicates `Loading...` or `Saving...`.  I end up make fewer trips to the `MOC` and avoiding a lot of complexity.

Comment: I need the entire context not just ids, ie tableviews and such.  Still passing around something all over the place, Ids, MOC same difference, make a storyboard change and its back to massive code updates.

Comment: Just to clarify, the WWDC 2014 session @Vader mentions talks about the history of Core Data concurrency models, rather than the history of how to pass around contexts themselves.